# How do I generate a List using tabulate who's entries are squared in Scala?

Tags: list, scala

I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to generate a List using the `tabulate()` method.

I see that it's used this way and it works perfectly fine,

```
val myList = List.tabulate(10)(_ * 2)
```

but this doesn't

```
val myList = List.tabulate(10)(_ * _)
```

whereas, I got what I wanted by,

```
val myList = List.tabulate(10)(n => n * n)
```

Can I know why didn't the second example work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An anonymous function represented with underscores is expected to have the same number of arguments as underscores. The particular overload of `List.tabulate` you are using (for one-dimension) expects a function with only argument, but you provide a function with two.

In other words `_ * _` expands to `(a, b) => a * b` and it is not possible to represent `a => a * a` with just underscores.

Alternatively, you could use `math.pow(_, 2)` as your squaring function, but it returns `Double` instead of `Int`.

```
scala> List.tabulate(10)(math.pow(_, 2))
res0: List[Double] = List(0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 9.0, 16.0, 25.0, 36.0, 49.0, 64.0, 81.0)
```

Comment: "and it is not possible to represent a => a * a with just underscores" - why not? I don't see any difficulty for the compiler / runtime to handle this scenario aptly, was this a conscious design choice?

Comment: @DineshBabu Since Scala function can have more than one argument, try it with `(a, b) => a * b + a`

Comment: I wonder why nobody invented something like `def twoArgs[A, B](x: A)(f: (A, A) => B ) = f(x, x)`? It would be fun: `List(1 ,2, 3).map(twoArgs(_)(_ * _))` :)

Comment: @DineshBabu Yes, it was a conscious design choice. It would make the compiler code much more complex if it had to also figure out how many arguments you intended.

Comment: @m-z Thanks, one more question, Can I assign the '_' to a variable inside the function and use that to perform the square operation? Is that legal in Scala?

Comment: @m-z If a function is returning only one argument, any number of uses of '_' inside the second function should refer to the same argument. Isn't this a simple way of implementing this?